# Tailwinds: How do you align to bottom an image and text on a flex?

Tags: tailwind-css

Please help... I'm trying to place an image and a text aligned to bottom using TailWindCSS. WHouldn't be complex if following the documentation.

```
<div class="flex"> // (1)
  <img
     src = "/img/square.png"
     class="inline-block h-10 align-bottom" // (2)
     >
  <span class="ml-4 align-bottom">align-bottom, yeah right</span> // (3)
</div>
```

(1) Here I have used `class="flex items-end"`

(2) Here I have used `inline-block` and without, same with `align-bottom` and all combinations

(3) Same here, I have used with `align-bottom` or without

Results are exactly the same, so I got no idea on what to do. Yes, I know I can use "plain" CSS to solve this, but I really want to know how to do this with TailWindCSS

This is what the code does:

[image]

############ EDIT

This is infuriating... This is the whole page HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">

</head>
<body>
  <div class="flex items-end">
    <img src="/img/square.png" class="inline-block h-12 align-bottom" />
    <span class="ml-4 align-bottom">Test</span>
  </div>

  <div class="flex items-end">
    <img src="http://jetbet.test/img/square.png" class="inline-block h-10 align-bottom" />
    <span class="font-bold text-red-300 align-bottom">Text</span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The lines are a copy & paste from https://play.tailwindcss.com/S6zNydSusV Here is what the tailwindcss produces:

[image]

...which is correct, and here's what my page produces:

[image]

I can't see what I'm doing wrong

Comment: A reproduction link would be good. You can see [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/W5j0IssOOr) that I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: I don't know... this is hyper-frustrating... here I put my code https://play.tailwindcss.com/S6zNydSusV just below yours, here, it works as it should be (I'm not that dumb reading documentation), then when I copy and paste in my system, in a clean HTML page, the thing just places the text aligned to the top

Comment: Nothing that Photoshop -or Paint for that matter- can't fix